# Not able to start wso2am-3.2.0 after server restore

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Our exiting wso2am-3.2.0 installation has corrupted so we are trying to restore the instance to a new server from our recent backup (November 28). The instance is pointed to the existing Postgres DB but we are not able to start the server. It is throwing bellow error. Please help

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-23 07:52:28,130] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegistry} - org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Error occurred while retrieving all node information. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-23 07:52:28,131] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.server.Main} - Exception during startup. Triggering shutdown org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Unable to initialise application registry
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startupImpl(Broker.java:312)
    
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Error occurred while retrieving all node information. 
    at org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegistry.initialise(ApplicationRegistry.java:266)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegistry.initialise(ApplicationRegistry.java:147)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startupImpl(Broker.java:279)
    ... 56 more
    
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Error occurred while retrieving all node information. 
    at org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreUtils.convertSQLException(RDBMSStoreUtils.java:128)
    at org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl.getAllStoredNodeData(RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl.java:419)
    
    
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "MB_NODE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT NODE_ID,NODE_DATA FROM MB_NODE [42102-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
```

Comment: Is it a single node all-in-one deployment? Have you changed any configuration changes since the last backup?

Comment: Format your error using code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We restored the \repository\database\WSO2MB_DB.mv.db from our old backup and the issue got resolved